# htaccess: remove trailing question mark and value after amp at the end of a url

Tags: htaccess

i'd like to remove question mark and value at the end of a url ending with amp.

For example, i want the following url:

http://www.domain.com/category/page.html/amp?value=12

to be like this:

http://www.domain.com/category/page.html/amp

What is the right way to do it using htaccess? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  .
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

You could test it e.g. [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)